# Two identical objective-c delegates - one works, the other does not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a 'home screen' that has two labels that holds counts. I have two different UIViewControllers that are delegates of the *HomeViewController*. *ViewControllerA* **will** call the method.

But *ViewControllerB* which is set up exactly the same, with the exception of naming, **will not** call the method.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**HomeViewController.h**

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerADelegate, ViewControllerBDelegate>
```

**HomeViewController.m**

```
- (void) updatedLabel {
    NSLog(@"Updating label count");
}

- (IBAction)btnA:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_a" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)btnB:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_b" sender:self];

}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue_a"]) {
        ViewControllerA * vca = (ViewControllerA*) segue.destinationViewController;
         vca.delegate = self;
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue_b"]) {
        ViewControllerB *vcb = (ViewControllerB*) segue.destinationViewController;
        vcb.delegate = self;
    }

}
```

**ViewControllerA.h**

```
@class ViewControllerA;

@protocol ViewControllerADelegate <NSObject>
- (void) updatedLabel;
@end

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ViewControllerADelegate> delegate;
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
- (IBAction)returnHome:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate updatedLabel];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**ViewControllerB.h**

```
@class ViewControllerB;
@protocol ViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) updatedLabel;
@end

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController<AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic)id <ViewControllerBDelegate> delegate;
```

**ViewControllerB.m**

```
- (IBAction)returnHome:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate updatedLabel];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your code? Where it is failing? What does work and what not? Are there any unexpected values?

Comment: I'm guessing that, at the time you do the second operation, that view controller has not been created yet and you're doing `setDelegate` on a nil pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for those experienceing similiar issues:
ViewControllerA was NOT embedded in a NavigationController.
ViewControllerB WAS embedded in a NavigationController.

User tgebarowski in a comment pointed out that if ViewControllerB is embedded in UINavigationController then segue.destinationViewController will return UINavigationController not ViewControllerB.

So to fix the issue, if you are creating a delegate through a Segue, use the following.

```
    UINavigationController * nvc = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    ViewControllerB *vcb = [nvc childViewControllers][0];
    vcb.delegate = self;
```

That's all there was to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are implementing ViewControllerADelegate and ViewControllerBDelegate protocols in HomeViewController. Both protocols have same method updatedLabel and this is ambiguous?

EDIT 1:
Check with debugger that vcb.delegate is not nil.

EDIT 2:
If your ViewControllerB is embedded in UINavigationController then segue.destinationViewController will return UINavigationController not ViewControllerB

Comment: I thought the same thing. At one point I made a different method just to test and it did not work.

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine. You basically promise to implement `updatedLabel ` *twice*. No potential for conflict here.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's going wrong. Time to roll up your sleeves and debug it. Set a breakpoint in your prepareForSegue and step through, making sure it sets the delegate on both classes of view controller. Also set a breakpoint on the returnHome method on both view controllers, and make sure the delegate property is not nil. Then when you get to the delegate call, click the "step into" button and watch it step into the delegate method.

Comment: Ok, I take back my original statement. Upon further inspection, the ViewControllerB is nil. But I don't understand why.

Comment: My ViewControllerB is Embedded in a Navigation Controller in the Storyboard. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Something is probably going wrong in your prepareForSegue method. Put a breakpoint there and single-step through it to see what happens.